# Cannot serialize member 'XXX' of type System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types

Tags: c#, web-services, subsonic

I'm getting the following error when using a web service:
Cannot serialize member 'XXX' of type System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.

I understand the error and found a solution on this blog:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120201220703/http://www.jamesewelch.com/2009/02/03/how-to-serialize-subsonic-objects-with-nullable-properties/

I would like to use solution 2, as you will see from my comments on the blog I'm not having much luck. I'm using an ExcuteTypeList to bring the data back.

Any pointers or help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your title addresses your original problem, but the question is regarding a completely different problem that you're not facing as a consequence of trying to correct the former; what exactly is the problem you're having with the `ShouldSerializeX` mechanism?

Comment: I'm still getting the error even when I have ShouldSerialize. If you can see my comments on the blog I think I've followed what was asked but still the error

Answer (score 16):

You need to remove [XmlAttribute] and apply [XmlElement] to the XXX field.

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] public decimal? XXX;

public bool ShouldSerializeXXX()
{
   return XXX.HasValue;
}
```